# Removing feature image from Wordpress post. (Dynamic News lite)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want my feature image to stop appearing on the post, I simply want to use it as thumbnail on recent post.

before asking here I tried a lots of different solutions.
I look for the responsible code in single.php but it was not there, 
I try to hide my feature image with CSS, when I check my site with firebug I notice that my CSS got overwritten by the orginal CSS, which does not happen normally.

After going through my code, I found this in template-tags.php

```
// Display Custom Header
if ( ! function_exists( 'dynamicnews_display_custom_header' ) ):

function dynamicnews_display_custom_header() {

    // Check if page is displayed and featured header image is used
    if( is_page() && has_post_thumbnail() ) :
    ?>
        <div id="custom-header" class="featured-image-header">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('custom_header_image'); ?>
        </div>
<?php
    // Check if there is a custom header image
    elseif( get_header_image() ) :
    ?>
        <div id="custom-header">
            <img src="<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>" />
        </div>
<?php
    endif;

}

endif;



 // Display Postmeta Data

if ( ! function_exists( 'dynamicnews_display_postmeta' ) ):

function dynamicnews_display_postmeta() {

    // Get Theme Options from Database
    $theme_options = dynamicnews_theme_options();

    // Display Date unless user has deactivated it via settings
    if ( isset($theme_options['meta_date']) and $theme_options['meta_date'] == true ) : ?>

        <span class="meta-date sep">
        <?php printf(__('<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>', 'dynamicnewslite'),
                esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
                esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
                esc_html( get_the_date() )
            );
        ?>
        </span>

    <?php endif;
```

I tried to remove some part of the code here, since I don't know anything about php, I get lots of error, I am hoping may be you guys can help me. 
I am using the theme dynamic news lite. 
here is the link to my site http://www.coolstuffgift.com/awesome-birthday-gifts-for-awesome-people/

Original code of Single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>



<div id="wrap" class="container clearfix">



    <section id="content" class="primary" role="main">



    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();



        get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );



        endwhile;



    endif; ?>



    <?php comments_template(); ?>



    </section>



    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>
```

This is all I got in single.php
I think the developer did some trick to hide the code.

Comment: the page you are seeing its `single.php` , please add the code from single.php file in question.

Comment: I just added the code of single.php also.

Comment: Please add the code of `single.php` which is inside`wp-content/themes/yourthemename/content/single.php`

Comment: you have any `content-single.php` this type of file in theme root path. ?? If yes then put it's code here.

Answer (score 0):

In your `content.php` OR `content-single.php` file.

Just comment `the_post_thumbnail()` this type of function.

Comment: Content-single.php 
 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

 

  <h1 class="post-title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

  

  <div class="postmeta"><?php dynamicnews_display_postmeta(); ?></div>

  

  <?php dynamicnews_display_thumbnail_single(); ?>

  

  <div class="entry clearfix">

   <?php the_content(); ?>

   <!-- <?php trackback_rdf(); ?> -->

   <div class="page-links"><?php wp_link_pages(); ?></div>   

  </div>

  

  <div class="postinfo clearfix"><?php dynamicnews_display_postinfo_single(); ?></div>



 </article>

Comment: hey guys, I solve it with you guys help,  I went to content-single.php and deleted this part of the code. <?php dynamicnews_display_thumbnail_single(); ?>, thanks a lot, one more question, do you think that I will have another side effect on my site other than what I want by deleting this code.

Comment: i think, by deleteing `dynamicnews_display_thumbnail_single(); ` this line  there are  no any side effect on your site. if your have any effect then plz tell me.